# Best practice to send OpenPGP encrypted messages to K-9 Mail on Android

Tags: pgp, openpgp

In  K-9 Mail, some OpenPGP encrypted messages are shown directly, some you have to download separately to decrypt them in APG.

There are some PGP/MIME or PGP/INLINE options in Thunderbird, you can choose when sending.

Which is the best practice to send the e-mail, so the recipient can view it directly inside  K-9 Mail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K9Mail only supports PGP/Inline, which is displayed as messages similar to the following one if not support for OpenPGP is installed/activated:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: GnuPG v1
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=ZK44
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

As of 2015-12-06, the alternative [PGP/MIME is not supported (yet) in K9mail](https://github.com/k9mail/k-9/milestones/PGP/MIME), and the encrypted content will get displayed as attachment. PGP/MIME is much less intrusive, especially when used for signatures for people without support for OpenPGP, where they will just see some signature attachment instead of the "weird looking unreadable "big block of jumbled characters on the bottom", with the obligatory XKCD reference:

[image: If you want to be extra safe, check that there's a big block of jumbled characters at the bottom.]

*From XKCD: [http://xkcd.com/1181/](http://xkcd.com/1181/_)*

Comment: Ah i see. There already is a high bounty on it: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/815255-pgp-mime